# Is there a word for the situation when everybody shuts up and stares at you?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Perhaps you say a bad joke or you make a really awkward noise, and everybody suddenly stares at you?

Comment: You'll have to clarify what it is that you're seeking, a mistake or silence?

Comment: I'm seeking for a mistake when everybody suddenly shut up, like a Murphy's Law situation: "you say something stupid or do an awkward action at the precise moment everybody shut up".

Comment: "A hush fell over the group" is a phrase to express this.

Comment: The question body and the title doesn't really match up. Please [edit] to clarify the real question. (When reading the title only, I thought of a situation where someone recalled a bad memory and everybody else shuts up because of the simpathy)

Comment: I had really hoped that this would just remain unanswered and uncommented. That would've been awkward. *crickets*

Comment: Just to clarify further, are we to understand that you are _not_ asking (as it first seemed) about a situation where everyone else stopped talking _because_ you did something awkward? There is a different thing that happens often in comedies, not so much in real life, in which a character is in a room where multiple independent conversations are taking place, and by bad luck all other conversations coincidentally fall silent at the exact instant that the character loudly says something embarrassing. Is that what you want to describe?

Comment: Just as you said, like second situation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This would be an [awkward silence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awkward_silence).

> An awkward silence is an uncomfortable pause in a conversation or presentation. The unpleasant nature of such silences is associated with feelings of anxiety as the participants feel pressure to speak but are unsure of what to say next.

Comment: Also *awkward pause* if you want to emphasize that there was conversation a moment ago. (*Awkward silence* can also be the starting state, for example when people haven't figured out how to introduce themselves or after introductions if they can't get a conversation started.)

Answer (score 17):

You could say that the room [**fell flat**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-flat)

> If a joke, idea, or suggestion falls flat, it does not have the intended effect:

*Cambridge Dictionary*

While it is primarily used to describe what was said, it can also be used to describe the room the statement was made in.

Alternatively, you could say that there was a **[deafening silence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deafening_silence)**

> **deafening silence**
>   A noteworthy silence, or absence of response, especially one signifying disapproval or lack of enthusiasm.
>   *The suggestion that they work through the holidays met with deafening silence.*

Comment: Great answer. **Fell flat** is a phrase not that common but should be.

Comment: quibble: I would say that the **joke** fell *flat*, or that the **room** fell *silent*, but I don't think you'd ever say that the **room** fell *flat*.

Comment: I agree with @Brondahl, the room falling flat sounds more like a structural catastrophe than a socially awkward situation.

Comment: If everyone shut up **because** of what you said, it could be a **stunned silence**.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully a useful contribution, though maybe not your preferred answer:

> [***faux-pas***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faux-pas) -
>   a slip or blunder in etiquette, manners, or conduct; an embarrassing social blunder or indiscretion.

(From dictionary.com)

This does not necessarily imply everyone stops talking and stares, though.  *Faux-pas* describes the "really bad joke or awkward noise."

Answer (score 4):

The word [conversation-ender](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Conversation-Ender) describes both the awkward statement and the pause in conversation that follows. I didn't find any better authoritative source than Urban Dictionary, but a Google search shows it is fairly commonly used.

> **Conversation-ender**
>
> A word, phrase or emotion that abruptly and awkwardly ends a conversation between two or more people. [spelling corrected]

Comment: A [conversation killer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Conversation%20killer) is the one I'm more familiar with.

Comment: I'm more familiar with [conversation-stopper](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conversation-stopper)

Answer (score 4):

I would describe it as a ***hush***. From the [Oxford English Dictioary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hush):

> A silence.

In particular, one will often say "[a hush fell over the room.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+hush+fell+over)" (*The Free Dictionary*, Idioms)

Answer (score 3):

**tumble weed**

> Describing unwanted silence and inactivity. Often used of a situation when one makes a statement that is ignored or ill-received from one’s audience. Gives the impression that a tumbleweed has passed through the room, as the resultant silence is likened to that of a desolate desert.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tumbleweed

Answer (score 2):

I've heard it called ***a pregnant silence*** - "silence" because there is no sound, "pregnant" because it is impregnated with relevance.

Comment: That's more commonly called a _pregnant pause_ and is a long pause made to raise expectations that what's going to be said next is going to be important.

Comment: @Blrfl +1. Good point. I agree that it is more commonly used than *pregnant silence*.