# What's the English equivalent to "svära i kyrkan" in Swedish?

Tags: idiom-requests, idiom-meaning, swedish

"Svära i kyrkan" literally means to swear in church, and to my understanding the figurative meaning is when someone says or does something that questions/defies a social norm in a softer manner than simply breaking rules. Its meaning is not just about misbehaving, but is a bit similar to the allegory of the child who points out that [the emperor is naked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes).

As an attempt to exemplify, one could use it to politely caution for (and/or) soften one's critique of a certain routine at work: "I may be swearing in church now, but is it absolutely necessary that we [insert redundant task] every Tuesday"?

Another example could be when a person is frank and outspoken, in other words not being afraid to swear in church.

Is there an English equivalent to the figurative meaning of the idiom?

Comment: Can you give a little more nuance to the Swedish phrase? Many things could be breaking social norms, but pointing out a truth that everyone is trying not to say (while possibly breaking a norm) is very very specific. If in fact your. example is just what you are looking for the usual way to say it "the emperor has no clothes" and is about that metaphor, not (at least not usually) about breaking the norm.

Comment: Noted. I've tried my best to exemplify.

Comment: "Speaking out of turn" might have some of the flavor that you're looking for.

Comment: You can "[ruffle someone's feathers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruffle%20feathers)" (or just "ruffle feathers" without identifying whose they are) when you're saying that you disturb other people's sense of propriety.

Comment: "I hope I'm not treading on anyone's toes but...", "I hope I'm not putting anyone's nose out of joint" or "speaking out of turn", as user888379 said. "I hate to be a spoilsport", "Call me an old cynic/fuddu-duddy/curmudgeon", "I don't want to frighten the horses" or "to ruffle any feathers", as Canadian Yankee said. "I hate to be a traditionalist but..." can be amusing. (In the Emperor's new clothes e.g.)

Comment: Related: [Is there a word for the situation when everybody shuts up and stares at you?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380598/is-there-a-word-for-the-situation-when-everybody-shuts-up-and-stares-at-you/380603#380603) (=> faux pas) // @user888379 I'd put that as an answer, possibly **the** answer.

Comment: @user3342816 I may be speaking out of turn, but the institution _Church_ is capitalised. Not the building.

Comment: It is often *used* in a way to *soften an opinion / argument*. That said: *at its core* it is far more egregious. One have to look at terms like respect, honor, sacred values etc. (Emph. historical context) Mocking something sacred; committing an *unheard of* violation of tact/norms. In a lot of today's society there are few things left that are sacred and the notion respect washed away. Point being, IMO, it is more grievous then it might sound in the Q. It's not about *"telling the truth"* or *"softer then breaking the rules"*. For the latter rather the opposite; i.e. *way over the line*.

Comment: I may be [***out of order*** here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-order), *(unpleasant or not suitable and likely to upset or offend people)* but I don't see why people can't say what they like in church.

Answer (score 2):

There is this.

> **faux pas**
> An embarrassing or tactless act or remark in a social situation.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/faux_pas)

Comment: Faux pas involves doing something objectively bad, a mistake, a blunder. I wouldn't say it is equivalent to what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

**mince no words**

> to speak in a very direct and honest way without worrying about offending someone

*She minces no words in stating her opinions.*

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ***heresy*** in the contexts you are given to express opposition to an accepted set of "rules" that "scandalises" everyone else. About ***heresy***, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heresy) says that it means:

> (the act of *having) an opinion or belief that is the opposite of or against what is the official or popular opinion*, or *an action that shows that you have no respect for the official opinion*
>
> - She ***committed the heresy*** of playing a Lady Gaga song on a classical music station.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heresy) explains that:

> ***Heresy*** *is a belief or action that most people think is wrong, because it disagrees with beliefs that are generally accepted*.
>
> - It might be considered ***heresy*** to suggest such a notion.

The expression ***commit the heresy of doing something*** (with the variant ***commit the sin of doing something***) is often used metaphorically as in your context:

> Sure, paint over ugly existing cheap bricks, but be careful not to commit the sin of covering a lovely old characterful wall. *Sunday Times* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/commit-a-sin))

So your example would look something like:

> I may be ***committing heresy*** now, but is it absolutely necessary that we [insert redundant task] every tuesday?

OR

> ***This might be considered heresy***, but is it absolutely necessary that we [insert redundant task] every tuesday?

Comment: Heresy would only be mild in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

"To be honest/frank...."
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-honest

It carries the connotation that normally people would elide the truth from tact in a a context.